# sharepoit performance counter instance name with [ACL]

Tags: sharepoint, performancecounter

Select a Sharepoint performance counter object, there are two instances for each of my web site. For example, for the ssp site, the two instance are named as

1. portnumber_ssp_admin
2. portnumber_ssp_admin[ACL]

What is the difference between the two instances? What is the meaning of [ACL]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL are access control lists, so it probably means the second one takes security into account.

Comment: You might be right. I remember that when defining cache profile, we have an option for ACL. That could be the meaning for [ACL].